# How shared memory would be accessed in manycore systems

Tags: c, multithreading, multicore

In multicore systems, such as 2, 4, 8 cores, we typically use mutexes and semaphores to access shared memory. However, I can foresee that these methods would induce a high overhead for future systems with many cores. Are there any alternative methods that would be better for future many core systems for accessing shared memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how far in the future you want to go. But in the long-long run, shared memory as we know it right now (single address space accessible by any core) is not scalable. So the programming model will have to change at some point and make the lives of programmers harder as it did when we went to multi-core.

But for now (perhaps for another 10 years) you can get away with transactional memory and other hardware/software tricks.

The reason I say shared-memory is not scalable in the long run is simply due to physics. (similar to how single-core/high-frequency hit a barrier)

In short, transistors can't shrink to less than the size of an atom (barring new technology), and signals can't propagate faster than the speed of light. Therefore, memory will get slower and slower (with respect to the processor) and at some point, it becomes infeasible to share memory.

We can already see this effect right now with NUMA on the multi-socket systems. Large-scale supercomputers are neither shared-memory nor cache-coherent.

Answer (score 6):

[Transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory) is one such method.

Comment: But its slow, isn't it? What is the fastest implementation out there?

Comment: This page may also help with more info: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Software_transactional_memory

Comment: @MetallicPriest - It is currently slower, but that seems in part due to the small number of cores, but, given problems with the lock approach, and how new it is, it is still probably the best approach at the moment.

Comment: There's a nice article about [IBM's Blue Gene](http://arstechnica.com/hardware/news/2011/08/ibms-new-transactional-memory-make-or-break-time-for-multithreaded-revolution.ars) supercomputer that puts this in context.

Comment: But I don't think it is scalable. Its main aim is to make programming easy and avoid bugs that can happen with locks.

Comment: You ask about the future in the question, but talk about the present in the comments. Transactional memory needs hardware implementation to fly. That will come.

Answer (score 0):

1) Lock only the memory part your are accessing, and not the entire table ! This is done with the help of a big hash table. The bigger the table, the finer the lock mechanism is.

2) If you can, only lock on writing, not on reading (this requires that there is no problem in reading the "previous value" while it is being updated, which is very often a valid case).

Answer (score 0):

Access to shared memory at the lowest level in any multi-processor/core/threaded application synchronization depends on the bus lock. Such a lock may incur hundreds of (CPU) wait states as it also encompasses locking those I/O buses that have bus-mastering devices including DMA. Theoretically it is possible to envision a medium-level lock that can be invoked in situations when the programmer is certain that the memory area being locked won't be affected by any I/O bus. Such a lock would be much faster because it only needs to synchronize the CPU caches with main memory which is fast, at least in comparison to latency of the slowest I/O buses. Whether programmers in general would be competent to determine when to use which bus lock adds worrying implications to its mainstream feasibility. Such a lock could also require its own dedicated external pins for synchronization with other processors.

In multi-processor Opteron systems each processor has its own memory which becomes part of the entire memory that all installed processors can "see". A processor trying to access memory which turns out to be attached to another processor will transparently complete the access - albeit more slowly - through a high-speed interconnect bus (called HyperTransport) to the processor in charge of that memory (the NUMA concept). As long as a processor and its cores are working with the memory physically connected to it processing will be fast. In addition, many processors are equipped with several external memory buses to multiply their overall memory bandwidth.

A theoretical medium-level lock could, on Opteron systems, be implemented using the HyperTransport interconnections.

As for any forseeable future the classic approach of locking as seldom as possible and for as short a time as possible by implementing efficient algorithms (and associated data structures) that are used when the locks are in place still holds true.